# Mule ESB: Streaming a large files/Multipart/form-data

Tags: ftp, mule

I a batch job that picks the file (larger than 200 MB) from FTP folder and we are doing a multipart/form data upload to an external service. The issue we are running into is out of memory and mule logs suggest enable streaming for FTP connector. If I enable streaming on the FTP connector then I am  getting a ‘no object DCH for mime type application/xml’ error. How do I set the content type for FTP file stream? 
Below is my config:

```html
     
<ftp:inbound-endpoint host="${ftp.host}" port="${ftp.port}" path="${ftp.path}" user="${ftp.user}" password="${ftp.password}" connector-ref="FTP" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP"/>
                <set-attachment attachmentName="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" value="#[message.payload]" contentType="application/xml" doc:name="Set File"/>
                <set-payload value="#[null]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
                <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="${api.importPath}//${api.files}" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP-Invoke Upload ">
                    <http:request-builder>
                        <http:header headerName="${access.token}" value="${access.token.value}"/>
                        <http:header headerName="${client.secret}" value="${client.secret.value}"/>
                        <http:header headerName="${authorization.mode}" value="${authorization.mode.value}"/>
                    </http:request-builder>
                </http:request>
 <ftp:connector name="FTP" pollingFrequency="1000" validateConnections="true" doc:name="FTP" streaming="true"/>
```

Thanks, 
ROA

Answer (score 0):

You have error message that  application/xml is not supported.
Try another mime type like text/plain here

```
<set-attachment attachmentName="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" value="#[message.payload]" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="Set File"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the mime type as below:

```
<set-attachment attachmentName="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" value="#[message.payload]" contentType="**/**" doc:name="Set File"/>
```